# Не работает eкзешник без Zedgraph.dll

Tags: c#

В одной папке имеется eкзешник и zedgraph.dll, но если я удаляю из папки zedgraph.dll то eкзешник не запускается. Как эту проблему решить. Надо чтобы программа запускалась без этой библиотеки. Можно ее как то включить в ексешник?

Comment: Решение простое: не удалять DLL, так как она является необходимой для работы приложения.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Как я не додумался...

Comment: Какую проблему вы *на самом деле* хотите решить?

Comment: DLL не предназначена для статической линковки, потому что это динамическая библиотека.

Comment: Надо чтоб программа запускалась с одного ексешника. Разве нельзя включить эту библиотеку в сборку(если я правильно выразился) перед релизом.

Comment: @SVD102 "DLL не предназначена для статической линковки" вам уже написали. Смотрите в сторону статической линковки, хотя есть подозрение что в .NET вы с этим и напляшитесь и налюбитесь...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов тут не подозрение, а утверждение. Это как пытаться запустить .NET приложение без .NET. Просто родные .NET DLL лежат не в в папке проекта а в GAC и на Win Vista+ в каком-то варианте установлены по умолчанию, поэтому появляется иллюзия что их нет. Но это всего лишь иллюзия

Comment: @rdorn ну я ни разу не спец по .NET, к счастью. Вот и всего лишь подозреваю.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов дык я ж не обвиняю, просто сообщаю =)

Comment: А как тогда эту библиотеку добавить к "родным" библиотекам.

Comment: Так на вскидку не помню, да и зачем? Это придется делать на каждой машине, где вы захотите запустить ваше приложение, что пожалуй только добавит "радости" пользователям. Лучше посмотрите в сторону публикации приложения ClickOnce, или запакуйте релиз в zip и отдавайте на скачивание архивом.

Comment: если очень хочется запихнуть сборку в GAC, почитайте тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Мне и надо добавить радости человеку который будет ей пользоваться на производстве)

Comment: Ну и вынесите этому вашему пользователю ярлык запуска приложения на рабочий стол. Тогда ему вообще будет не интересно где расположен исполняемый файл и какие там рядом с ним ещё библиотеки.

Comment: @rdorn А можно из обычной консоли добавить dll файл к родительским?

Answer (score 6):

Как это делаю я:

1. Добавляю сборку как обычный файл явно в проект.
2. Указываю сборке (пкм по ней, свойства) Build Action - Embedded Resource, Do not copy.
3. На запуске приложения подписываюсь на событие резолва сборок

   ```
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly.ResolveInternalAssembly;

   internal static Assembly ResolveInternalAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   {
     var resource = args.Name;
     var resourceNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
     if (!resourceNames.Any())
       return null;

     if (resource.Contains(','))
       resource = resource.Substring(0, resource.IndexOf(','));

     var assemblyFile = string.Format(".{0}.dll", resource);
     var resourceName = resourceNames.SingleOrDefault(s => s.EndsWith(assemblyFile));
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceName))
     {
       assemblyFile = assemblyFile.Remove(0, 1);
       resourceName = resourceNames.SingleOrDefault(s => s.EndsWith(assemblyFile));
     }

     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceName))
       return null;

     using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
     {
       var block = new byte[stream.Length];
       stream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
       return Assembly.Load(block);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: интересный вариант, а в чем плюсы и минусы? не для поспорить, просто интересно.

Comment: @rdorn все либы внутри, простая такая portable программа.

Comment: а на время запуска не сказывается?

Comment: Когда какой то nhibernate запускается секунды 3, доступ к либам не ощутим, например.

Comment: ок, спасибо, еще один прием в копилку.

Comment: Немного по теме: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Есть утилиты, которые собирают ехе-шник с несколькими библиотеками в один - это ILMerge, libz

Comment: Это не пойдёт, если библиотека нативная. А так вообще хороший вариант.

Comment: @VladD да, конечно. по чесноку, мне больше нравится решение с EmbeddedResource

Comment: @VladD, а как осуществляется поиск нативных библиотек? Мое решение подозреваю тоже для них не сработает, т.к. они не вызывают событие, видимо.

Comment: @kvvk: У решения с `AssemblyResolve` та же проблема, в общем-то. Загрузка нативных библиотек не настолько гибкая. (Хотя, возможно, есть WinAPI'шные хуки.)

Comment: @Monk: Угу, это только для .NET-сборок.

Comment: @Monk: Алгоритм поиска нативных библиотек как в нативных приложениях: текущий каталог, каталог приложения, %PATH%, C:\Windows\, known dlls и т. д.